# Control Public File Response Code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Let's say that I have a POST endpoint in my Rails app, in which it gets a param called state, which will be an integer of either 200 or 503.

**How** can I make the Robots.txt file respond with the given state from that POST endpoint, I mean I need a way to control the response code of that only file (Robots.txt) depending on that POST endpoint.

**BTW**, question is not about how to store that state or something, it's only about how to change the response code of a public file?

Is that possible?

What I have in mind for this and trying now is to have a controller action matching the robots.txt route, but I feel this is so silly to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want Rails to be involved in deciding the response for a given URL, then you're going to want to define a controller action to handle those requests.

You can use [`send_file`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) to actually do the file-sending part.

Depending on your web server's configuration, it's likely you'll need the actual `robots.txt` file to be stored somewhere other than `public/` -- otherwise it might get served without Rails even having a chance to get involved.

---

You *could* instead arrange to rewrite your nginx (say) configuration file at runtime, based on what response code you want... but I think *that* would be silly to do.

A more practical middle-ground would be to have Rails create or delete a marker file, and then use a conditional in the nginx configuration based on whether that file exists. That would be an [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) question though... and would get complicated if you have more than one server.